# Unable to manipulate spree commerce views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to customize my spree commerce store.

In particular, I would like to make a change to the "cart" page (`localhost:3000/cart`, assuming spree is mounted at `localhost:3000`) that shows all the items that are currently in your cart and allows you to go to checkout.

Looking at spree source code on github, i can see where this view belongs via the following route:

```
get '/cart', :to => 'orders#edit', :as => :cart
```

So i look into `app/views/spree/orders/` and i find `edit.html.erb`, and overlooking the code, it corresponds to the view at `localhost:3000/cart`, however any changes I make to it do not register at all. I have even tried removing all the code that is in the file, yet nothing happens. I've made sure it is saved, I have refreshed, and have even restarted the server.

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

update: i've checked the GET requests in the terminal after clicking "cart". It of course makes a GET request for `/cart` and this eventually turns into `Processing by Spree::OrdersController#edit as HTML`. So it's definitely going to `Orders#edit`

update 2: Ok I've figured it out. Spree is somehow cacheing the cart, so I have to empty the cart, go back to the home page, fill it up again, and then open it to see changes. If anyone can concretely answer what is going on, please do. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting.  What do the logs say when you load the cart? Any typos in the path?  app/views/spree/orders/edit.html.erb

Comment: What version of Spree are you using? What kind of change do you want to make?

Comment: @mvidaurre using version 2.3.1. I want to remove some elements on the page, but I clearly can't do so, as I've tried removing all the code for the page, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Demosophy Which logs do you want to check, how do I check them? Are you referring to my terminal after I start the server?